# Delete realm if manual migration fails

Tags: android, realm

Currently I am using

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
.build()
```

Which is nice while developing, but not ideal when releasing updates to the app store. 
I have wrote migration code using RealmMigration so that users do not have their Realm wiped upon update.

But now migrations will become an annoyance while developing if I ever make any changes to the schema.

Is there anyway to have Realm try and use the migration... and if the migration fails just have realm deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
try {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    realm.close();
} catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e) {
    Realm.deleteRealm(config);
}
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Comment: yes, but would be annoying to have to do that every time I get a realm instance

Comment: You only have to do it once - when the app starts. But feel free to create a  feature request at the Realm Java github repository.

Comment: Good point, the only problem with you code is it that when you provide a migration in your configuration RealmMigrationNeededException is not the ony error that could be thrown. Instead of only catching RealmMigrationNeededException I am also catching the errors that could occur with a bad migration and then deleting the realm.